# Non-parametric version of German Tanks problem?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, order-statistics

The German Tank Problem assumes that we observe k i.i.d. random variables $X_1,...,X_k$ uniformly distributed over $[0,N]$, where $N$ is unknown.

The goal in this problem is to estimate $N$ given the observed data.  If $m = \max(X_1,...,X_k)$, then we can infer the probability mass function
$$\Pr(N=n \mid m,k) = \begin{cases}
   0 &\text{if } n < m \\
   \frac {k - 1}{k}\frac{\binom{m - 1}{k - 1}}{\binom n k} &\text{if } n \ge m,
\end{cases}$$
to obtain an estimate of $N$ using maximum likelihood.

Does this problem have a solution when  $X_1,...,X_k$ are drawn i.i.d. from an unknown distribution with support $[0,N]$? Is there an estimate for $\hat{N}$ that we can infer even if we do not make an assumption that the data are uniform?

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. The domain for this problem is $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and the variables are not IID because they are obtained without replacement, i.e. if $X_1=6$, then $X_2 \neq 6$ is granted, so $X_2$ is not uniform in $\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Maximum-likelihood estimation involves maximisation of the likelihood function, which is not well-defined unless we have a specified class of sampling densities, parameterised (at least in part) by the parameter you want to estimate.

In the case where you merely posit that you have *some* distribution concentrated on $0, 1, ..., N$, this is a non-parametric problem, and you will need to be a bit clearer about exactly what class of allowable distributions you are using.  You could take this to mean that you are looking at the class of all possible distributions on this discrete range with $\mathbb{P}(X=N) >0$ (i.e., the value $N$ must have positive probability, but the previous values might not be in the support).  If this is the interpretation of your non-parametric class of distributions then the (trivial) maximum likelihood estimate of the distribution is the empirical distribution of the data, and the MLE is $\hat{N} = \max x_i$.

Answer (score 2):

The MLE for the German tank problem is trivially $\hat{N} = \max x_i$ even if we restrict ourselves to uniform distributions; the right hand side of the OP's displayed equation is decreasing in $n$.

In a frequentist setting, the minimum variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) $\hat{N} = m(1+k^{-1})-1$ is usually used.  (In the continuous case, there is no "$-1$".)

Again, it is not possible to ensure that an estimator is unbiased (which is necessary for it to be an MVUE) unless there is an assumed distribution.  It would be possible to minimize the variance given some other non-degeneracy condition, but it isn't clear what condition would be suitable.

In reference to Carlos's correct comment that the values are drawn without replacement, there is also a continuous version of the problem, in which replacement is a non-issue (since drawing a countable number doesn't alter the probabilities).  That would be the case if the support were indeed $[0,N]$, which is a continuous interval.  However, the displayed equation doesn't apply to this case.